# Как реализовать динамический массив? C++

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, выделение-памяти

Есть программа сортировки одномерного массива из 25 элементов. Как сделать программу, которая могла бы сортировать одномерный массив любой размерности? Если вас не затруднит, объясните, как правильно выделять память под динамический массив, пользоваться указателями и оператором "&" для получения значения по указанному адресу, спасибо за помощь, вот код для массива из 25 элементов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main(void) {
char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");


     << "Введите массив А, состоящий из 25 целых чисел." << endl
     << "Программа  определит и выведет на экран максимальный нечетный элемент массива." << endl
     << "Ожидание ввода..." << endl;

 int N=25;


int k, max;

// Объявляем массив на 25 целых чисел и заполняем его с клавиатуры
int A(N){};
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    k = (i+1);
    cout << k << " элемент = ";
    cin >> A[i];

}


max = A[0];
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0){
        if (max < A[i]) {
            max = A[i];
            k = (i+1);
        }
    }
}
cout << "Максимальный нечетный " << k <<" элемент массива = " << max << endl << "===================================" << endl << endl;

cout << "Вывод массива до сортировки" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << A[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
    int mindex = i;

    int tmp = 0;

    for (int j=i+1; j < N; j++) {
        if (A[j] < A[mindex]) {
            mindex = j;
        }
    }
    if (i != mindex) {
        tmp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[mindex];
        A[mindex] = tmp;
    }
}
cout << "Вывод массива после сортировки" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cout << A[i] << ' ';
}
cout << endl;



return 0;
}
```

Код с вектором

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <clocale>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <vector>

  using namespace std;
  int main(void)
 {
char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

cout << "Введите массив А, состоящий из N целых чисел." << endl
     << "Программа  определит и выведет на экран максимальный нечетный элемент массива." << endl
     << "Ожидание ввода N..." << endl;

 int N;
 cin >> N;

int max, k;

// Объявляем массив на 25 целых чисел и заполняем его с клавиатуры
vector <int> A[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    k = (i+1);
    cout << k << " элемент = ";
    cin >> A[i];

}


max = A[0];
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0){
        if (max < A[i]) {
            max = A[i];
            k = (i+1);
        }
    }
}
cout << "Максимальный нечетный " << k <<" элемент массива = " << max << endl << "===================================" << endl << endl;


cout << "Вывод массива до сортировки" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << A[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
    int mindex = i;

    int tmp = 0;

    for (int j=i+1; j < N; j++) {
        if (A[j] < A[mindex]) {
            mindex = j;
        }
    }
    if (i != mindex) {
        tmp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[mindex];
        A[mindex] = tmp;
    }
}
cout << "Вывод массива после сортировки" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cout << A[i] << ' ';
}
cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Спасибо всем кто помог. Вот код через указатели.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <clocale>
  #include <cmath>

  using namespace std;
  int main(void)
  {
  char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  cout << "Введите массив А, состоящий из N целых чисел." << endl
  << "Программа  определит и выведет на экран максимальный нечетный элемент 
 массива." << endl
 << "Ожидание ввода N..." << endl;

  int N;
  cin >> N;

   int max, k;


   int *A = new int[N]();
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    k = i+1;
    cout << k << " элемент = ";
    cin >> A[i];

    }


    max = A[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0){
      if (max < A[i]) {
        max = A[i];
        k = (i+1);
      }
    }
  }
cout << "Максимальный нечетный " << k <<" элемент массива = " << max << 
endl << "===================================" << endl << endl;


cout << "Вывод массива до сортировки" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cout << A[i] << ' ';
}
cout << endl << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
int mindex = i;

int tmp = 0;

for (int j=i+1; j < N; j++) {
    if (A[j] < A[mindex]) {
        mindex = j;
    }
}
if (i != mindex) {
    tmp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[mindex];
    A[mindex] = tmp;
}
  }
        cout << "Вывод массива после сортировки" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     cout << A[i] << ' ';
     }
     cout << endl;
     delete [] A;
     return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, вам нужен просто массив, в который вы сможете сложить заранее неизвестное количество элементов (с возможностью увеличения их количества в дальнейшем), или же вы хотите реализовать класс, который даёт эту функциональность?(другими словами, сделать собственную реализацию `std::vector`'а)

Comment: @zcorvid нужен просто динамический массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Память под "голый" массив неизвестного размера в С++ можно выделить так

```
int *A = new int[N];
```

Элементы такого массива будут изначально содержать "мусор". В вашем коде вам фактически не нужна изначальная инициализация элементов массива, но если вам так больше нравится, вы можете сделать

```
int *A = new int[N]();
// или
int *A = new int[N]{};
```

В этих вариантах содержимое массива будет изначально обнулено.

Когда такой массив становится ненужным, память следует освободить через

```
delete[] A;
```

Остальной код при этом менять не нужно.

---

Однако, если уж вам нужен "голый" массив, то лучше поступить так

```
#include <memory>
...

std::unique_ptr<int []> A(new int[N]);
```

С таким указателем/массивом можно работать обычным образом (т.е. `A[i]`), но память будет освобождена автоматически.

Answer (score 4):

Раз тег с++ стоит, так будем делать по с++сному.

Вначале в самом верху добавим ещё один инклуд

```
#include <vector>
```

вектор - это то, что обычно нужно, когда хочется расширяющийся массив (массив произвольного размера).

Вместо `int N = 25;` пишем `int N; cin >> N;`
Вместо `int A[N];` пишем так `vector<int> A(N);`

Все, готово!

Comment: А через указатели нельзя сделать? Хотелось бы разобраться именно с ними.

Comment: А зачем? Хотите указатели - лучше переходите на чистый си. или Вы хотите через new/delete?

Comment: Через вектор выдает много ошибок. прилагаю код в отредактированном вопросе.

Comment: М, ну разве я здесь `vector <int> A[N];` написал квадратные скобки? там круглые должны быть.

Comment: Работает, спасибо.