# Как создать динамический массив? Указатели, выделение памяти, оператор "&"

Tags: c, динамические-массивы, выделение-памяти

Задавал этот вопрос в категории С++. Подсказали решение проблемы через вектор, но в С нет вектора, поэтому вопрос как пользоваться динамическими массивами все еще интересует меня.

Есть программа сортировки одномерного массива из N элементов на с++. Реализована с помощью vector. Как сделать программу, которая могла бы сортировать одномерный массив любой размерности на языке С? Если вас не затруднит, объясните, как правильно выделять память под динамический массив, пользоваться указателями и оператором "&" для получения значения по указанному адресу, спасибо за помощь, вот код на С++.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <clocale>
  #include <vector>

   using namespace std;
   int main(void) {
   char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

   cout << "Введите массив А, состоящий из N целых чисел." << endl
   << "Программа  определит и выведет на экран максимальный нечетный элемент 
   массива." << endl
   << "Ожидание ввода N..." << endl;

    int N;
    cin >> N;

    int max, k;


    vector <int> A[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    k = (i+1);
    cout << k << " элемент = ";
    cin >> A[i];
    }


  max = A[0];
 for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
  if (i%2 == 0){
    if (max < A[i]) {
        max = A[i];
        k = (i+1);
    }
   }
  }
  cout << "Максимальный нечетный " << k <<" элемент массива = " << max << 
  endl << "===================================" << endl << endl;
  cout << "Вывод массива до сортировки" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     cout << A[i] << ' ';
  }
  cout << endl << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
      int mindex = i;
      int tmp = 0;

     for (int j=i+1; j < N; j++) {
        if (A[j] < A[mindex]) {
        mindex = j;
        }
     }
if (i != mindex) {
    tmp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[mindex];
    A[mindex] = tmp;
}
}
  cout << "Вывод массива после сортировки" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  cout << A[i] << ' ';
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать динамический массив? C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/926839/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)

Comment: Вы просто скопипастили свой предыдущий вопрос, поменяв пару слов?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Да, это мой вопрос, но разобраться-то нужно с указателями, поэтому переместил его в категорию С-вопросов

Comment: То, что вам сказали в прошлом вопросе "указатели - это вам надо на чистом Си программировать" - бред. `new/delete` вместо `malloc/free` в С++ добавили не просто так.

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, что именно вам надо: программа на С или программа на С++ "с указателями"? Это сильно разные вещи (несмотря на иногда встречающиеся тут попытки утверждать обратное).

Comment: @RiotBr3aker то есть в С++ тоже объявляют динамические массивы через new, как в Java?

Comment: @AnT Если в С++ используют указатели, а не вектор для объявления динамических массивов, то в идеале разобраться и с С и с С++, простите если слишком многого хочу))

Comment: Не надо "слишком много" в одном вопросе. На этом вопросе вы поставили тэг [C]. Это значит, что вы хотите вариант именно на С. Это так? Или вы просто перепутали тэг? Если вам нужен вариант с указателями на С++ - то так и скажите в вашем исходном вопросе и гоните в шею всех, кто лезет в ответы с советами про `std::vector`.

Comment: @AnT Да, нужно разобраться с указателями на С, вопрос про С++ отредактирую.

Comment: @AnT, в прошлом вопросе так, собственно, и произошло.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, нет, `new` в Jave'e - это немного другая тема, не надо все в одну кучу мешать. `new/delete` в С++ - очень даже легальная штука, и ее желательно понять, прежде чем работать с векторами.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Хорошо, почитаю про new в Java. Почему у меня сложилось такое мнения, в видео-уроках показано, да и в университете, мне сказали, что в С++ и в Java для выделения памяти под массив используют new. Страшно интересно теперь в чем подвох))

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, технически это так, но есть свои особенности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вместо заголовков стандартной библиотеки C++ включаем заголовки стандартной библиотеки C: `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<locale.h>`.
2. Вместо `vector <int> A[N];` делаем

   ```
   int *A = malloc(N * sizeof *A);
   ```

   или

   ```
   int *A = сalloc(N, sizeof *A);
   ```

   (если вы хотите получить обнуленный массив).
3. Имеет смысл проверить успешность выделения памяти

   ```
   if (A == NULL)
     /* Не удалось выделить память */;
   ```
4. В конце программы не забываем сделать

   ```
   free(A);
   ```
5. Ввод-вывод заменяем на функции стандартной библиотеки C: `printf` и `scanf`. Разумеется, убираем всякие `using namespace ...`.

Всё.

---

Однако в языке С у вас есть возможность пользоваться массивами переменной длины (VLA). Если ваша реализация поддерживает VLA и если величина `N` не будет заоблачно большой, то можно просто объявить

```
int A[N];
```

и ни о чем больше не беспокоиться.

---

P.S. От странной манеры ставить лишние скобки в выражениях (напр. в `k = (i+1);`) тоже не мешало бы избавиться.